# .net progress bar in a asp.net we application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, controls, progress-bar

Is it possible to have a .net progress bar in a asp.net web application.

I tried doing this:

```
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    pb.Name = "pb";
    pb.Value = 30;

    pb.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;

    pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);

    pb.Width = 200;
    pb.Height = 30;
    Controls.Add(pb);
```

but this :

```
Controls.Add(pb);
```

Doesnt work,

Any idea how to do this? or something the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

no this is not possible - ASP.NET pages are just rendered HTML that gets send to the client (web-browser). The progress-bar is a client-side control.

If you need something like this on the client you may to use Javascript/JQuery/AJAX or something similar.

Here is a version for [JQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryProgressBar)
And here is a nice [article](http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/) on this with AJAX

Comment: Thank you. i need a progress bar that will update it self when getting data from the server an update a grid view. how should i do that?

Comment: I guess you load the data for the grid-view on your server so the response will only be sent to the client after all the data are loaded. If this takes to long you have to get all the way with AJAX and co. (return the page but load the data in the background and use AJAX to return it / load it) - there are some nice articles on the net concerning this stuff and maybe there are some inbuild goodies in ASP.NET Webforms but I'm more the MVC/JQuery guy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this control on web.

Comment: Thank you. i need a progress bar that will update it self when getting data from the server an update a grid view. how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to write an algorithm(maybe using an async call) to update the progress bar.it won't work if you use the classic request/response because you would not have the chance to update your progress bar. you need a way to read a kind of value at regular interval to update the progress bar and give the perception to the users that something is happening. If you want to go for a "fake" one you could use the one showed at the link below:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/